# How to go capture the response time of executing multiple queries simultaneously in Java?

Tags: java, sql, multithreading

I am developing a Java tool, which has to take as input a text file containing a set of queries (around 1000), execute them together, and print out the response time each query took.

I reckon we need to use threads for this. How do we go about it? Should we create a connection first, and then start a new thread for each query?

The requirement is to create a file with the queries along with the response time printed alongside.

Additionally

1. Planning to get the DB connection from main prog, pass it to thread along with the query wherein the query is executed. Is this the right way?
2. Since it'l be a text file, will be getting all the queries in an arraylist, and will be calling the threads from a while iterator loop. Any better ways?
3. How do I write the response times? Should I store all the queries along with the times, and finally write it to a text file, or should i write it as soon as each query is executed from the threads?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit : It's a tool developed for the performance team to check the response time of queries when there are about 1000 concurrent hits to the DB.

Comment: Why do you suppose that you need threads? Firing 1000 concurrent queries at an RDBMS is going to cause all 1000 queries to run slower than if you fired them sequentially. You *may*, however, complete the batch, as a whole, quicker by running them concurrently *(each one is slower, but the whole batch takes less time due to the concurrency)*. So, what are you trying to measure and why? *(If you do go the concurrency route, each thread needs its own connection.)*

Comment: @Dems The application might be having these many (1000) concurrent hits to the DB, and we are checking how much time the queries might take in this scenario, Isnt threads the way to do that? Its just a tool used internally and not part of the application

Comment: @GaryF I have tried whats been given in the additional points. I hav tried this with 2-3 queries. Since I'm not much familiar with threads, I'm just concerned if this is the right way ( using threads) and if yes, whether I'm using threads correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague.
For example do you have e.g. 1000 SQL to pass to the SQL server to execute as a batch?
In this case you can just do:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
execute SQL script  
System.out.println("took:"+System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

If you have a series of sql queries to be run as separate actions from your application and want to measure the average time, you can use an executor to submit the tasks, add the time for each (similar to above) and in the end divide by number of queries done.

UPDATE:
You can use a thread pool for this.
Example (omitted exception handling):

```
   Collection<Callable<Long>> sqlTasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Long>>();  
   sqlTasks.add(new Callable<Long>(){  

    @Override  
    public Long call() throws Exception {  
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        // DO SQL QUERY HERE   
        //return delay  
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;  
       }  
    });  
    //ADD MORE TO THE QUEUE 
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  
    List<Future<Long>> results = threadPool.invokeAll(sqlTasks);  
    long totalDelay = 0;  
    for(Future<Long> delay:results){  
        System.out.println("Delay for task"+delay.get());  
        totalDelay += delay.get();  
    }  
    System.out.println("Average Delay per task"+totalDelay / sqlTasks.size());
```

You add the SQL queries to a queue and they are executed by threads in the [thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and each returns its delay.
But you should also mention which SQL DB you are trying. Perhaps there is already a performance tool for that

Comment: As i said, the main aim is to check the response time each query takes, if they are to hit the DB simultaneously from the application. This scenario has to be simulated in Java, for which I think threads is the right way. If not could you tell me how do I go about it?

Comment: @Chillax:You have e.g. SQL Query A, SQL Query B, SQL Query C etc (which are `INSERT`, `SELECT` etc) and you want to find the time to execute each query from the Java application?What do you want to measure exactly?The performance of the SQL Server or you want to see how much each query takes from java?

Comment: I want to check how much each query might take when all the three queries are executed at the same time. I am building a Java tool to get these details, and it is to test the performance of the SQL Server, to see how it performs when a large number of hits come simultaneously

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am getting the connection, using a while loop to iterate through the set of queries, creating a new Runnable thread for  each query in the loop and starting it, and getting the response time for each query from the run() method. Is there any disadv with this method?

Comment: `run` does not return a result.So you are accesing shared variables to update the response time.As long as you keep the access synchronized so that the delay is correctly updated, it seems ok

Comment: Thanks. Also its not the average time I'm interested in. But the time each query takes. The above works in this scenario right. We can print out the delay with these steps inside the run() method yea : 1. Get the start time 2. Execute Query 3. Print time taken = end .time- start time.  How do we make sure that the time printed out is for that query alone?

Comment: @Chillax:What you measure is the delay of the time you send a request over the JDBC to the time you receive the result.So overall you account for any delay from the SQL server till it executes your query.If you don't want to account for that then you should send your requests sequentially to make sure that the SQL server processes them as soon as they arrive